# Redirect to another page and pass parameter via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to pass parameter in a ASP.NET page to another page (in our web site) by redirecting using JavaScript (or jQuery, Ajax, Fetch, etc.) and catch this parameter on Load event of the redirected page via JavaScript. However, I am not sure if I can do this. Any idea?

***News Page:***

```
window.location = '/news/details?id=4';
```

***Details Page:***

```
$(function (id) {
    console.log('Pass parameter: ' + id);        
});
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Where is the parameter that is being passed being captured from? URL, cookie, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

On the Details page, use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object to get access to the url params, for example:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
console.log(url.searchParams.get("id"));
```

Comment: You're welcome @ClintEastwood, and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the parameters from the url in your details page with the following code:

```
var url = new URL(window.location);
var param = url.searchParams.get("parameterName");
```

As @Michael Hurley  points out, `url` is not available in some browsers (namely IE), so if you need to support them you'll have to do some additional work:

```
exp = /(?:parameterName=)(\w)/
match = str.match(exp)
//match[1] would hold the value of 'parameterName'
```

Comment: Be advised, [URL is not supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=url)